# Set cookie and update cookie problem - Php

Tags: php

In an attempt to get more familiar with cookies I've decided to set up a simple cookie management system to have more control of the information that I can store and retrieve from a user.

The idea is to set a cookie if it does not exist, and update a cookie if it already exists on the user.

Once the cookie is set, it will also be stored in a database that will keep track on when the session started and when it was last accessed.

Creating a cookie worked well at first. But suddenly it stopped working and wouldn't set anything at all. This is the current code of the createSession() function:

```
function createSession() {

// check to see if cookie exists
if(isset($_COOKIE["test"])) {
            // update time
    $expire = time()+81400;
    setcookie("test","$cookiekey",$expire,"/",false,0);
} else {
    // assign unique cookie id
    list($msec,$sec)=explode(" ",microtime());
    $cookiekey = preg_replace("/./","",($msec+$sec));
            // set time
    $expire = time()+81400;

    // set cookie
    setcookie("test","$cookiekey",$expire,"/",false,0);

    // assign the unqiue id to $_COOKIE[]
    $_COOKIE["test"]=$cookiekey;
    unset($cookiekey);unset($msec);unset($sec);unset($expire);
   }
```

}

Is my approach heading in the right direction or have I done something way wrong?

Comment: you are actually creating a cookie with name `name` and checking with the `$_COOKIE["test"]`

Comment: *Changed it, but there is still no cookie detected by the browser

Answer (score 4):

Doing `$_COOKIE["test"] = something;` doesn't make a "test" cookie. You need to use setcookie again.

I don't know why you'd want to do that though. Why not just check for $_COOKIE["name"] (the cookie that you *are* making).

Comment: The idea is to assign the 'microtime id' to the cookie so that I can print it along with other cookie information later on.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are only available once another request was done. So don’t modify `$_COOKIE` on your own.

Furthermore, when in your case the cookie exists (i.e. `$_COOKIE['test']` is set) you call `setcookie` again with `$cookiekey` as its value. But `$cookiekey` is not defined at that moment so the cookie will be overwritten with an empty string. I guess you want to use `$_COOKIE['test']` instead:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["test"])) {
    // update time
    $expire = time()+81400;
    setcookie("test", $_COOKIE["test"], $expire, "/", false, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also save yourself all that pain by using PHP's [built in session management](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) (examples [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html)) to handle all of this cookie stuff for you.

Comment: I merely try to learn by doing. Great example by the way, I'll dive into it.

Comment: $_SESSION is extremely nice and helpful, and based on cookies, so learning how to play around with cookies is essential to use $_SESSION.

Comment: Learning how to play around with cookies is not required for using session at all; the session management takes care of that for you automatically.